# Multi threading read and write file using python

Tags: python, multithreading

So, I have a 9000 lines csv file. I have read it and stored it in a dictionary list with string key, m. What I want to do is to loop for every item `list[m]` and process it into a function `processItem(item)`. This `processItem` will return a string with csv-like format. My aim is to write the result of `processItem` function for every item in list. Is there any idea how to do this multi thread way?

I think I should divide the list to N sub-lists and then process these sub-lists in multi thread way. Every thread will return the string processed from sub-lists and then merge it. Finally write it to a file. How to implement that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a perfect example for using the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) module and the [`Pool()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) function (be aware that `threading` module can not be used for speed).

You have to apply a function on each element of your list, so this can be easily parallelized.

```
with Pool() as p:
    processed = p.map(processItem, lst)
```

If you are using Python 2, `Pool()` cannot be used as a context manager, but you can use it like this:

```
p = Pool()
processed = p.map(processItem, lst)
```

Your function `processItem()` will be call for each element in your `lst`, and the result will create a new list `processed` (order is preserved).

The function `Pool()` spawn as many process workers that your CPU has cores, and it executes new task as soon as the previous one is finished, until every elements has been processed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to implement this.